# Reloading google maps using mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am designing a system based on Google Maps and GPS. I am receiving the GPS information in my server every 10 seconds, and using a Java program it stores the latitude and longitude in a mysql database. Also, I'm making a website with google maps with the idea of tracking the device in real time.

The problem I'm having is that I need to query the mysql table every 10 seconds to retrieve the latitude+longitude, and the only way I have found so far is calling the php code over and over again, meaning with this:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('google-map').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
    },10000);
</script>

<iframe height="540" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="10" marginwidth="0" width="100%" name="google-map" id="google-map"
src="google-map.php">
</iframe>
```

I am calling the php code under the name of google-map.php:

```
<?php
include_once("includes/checksession.php");
include_once("dbconn/dbconn.php");
$db = new runQuery();
$db->Dbconn(); //until now I just connect to my DB

    $user_id    =   @$_SESSION['user_id'];

    $sel_qry = "select * from Historico where Gps_Gpscol=\"$user_id\" order by Fecha desc limit 1";
    $res_qry   =  mysql_query($sel_qry);    
    $num        = mysql_num_rows($res_qry);
    $row        = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry);

    $latitude   =   $row['Latitud'];

    $lat_array = explode('.',$latitude);

    $lat_deg = $lat_array[0];

    $lat_array_new = explode(' ',$lat_array[0]);
    $lat_deg = $lat_array_new[0];
    $longitude  =   explode(".",$row['Longitud']);      

    $long_1 = explode(" ",$longitude[0]);

    $long_deg = $long_1[0];
    $long_min = $long_1[1];
    $long_sec = $longitude[1];

    $lat_new  = $lat_deg.'.'.$lat_min.$lat_sec;
    $long_new = $long_deg.'.'.$long_min.$long_sec;

    [NOT RELEVANT CODE.. SUPRESED]

$nombre_format_lat = number_format($lat, 6, '.', ' ');
$nombre_format_long = number_format($long, 6, '.', ' ');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Kiwi</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadGmaps() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng('-<?php echo $nombre_format_lat; ?>', '-<?php echo $nombre_format_long; ?>');
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: myLatlng,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
            },

            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
            },
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

        var image = {
            url: 'img/kiwi.png',
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30,30)
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MyGmaps"), myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: '-<?php echo $row['Latitud']; ?> -<?php echo $row['Longitud']; ?>',
                icon: image,
                draggable: true
            });

            var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng('-34.607900','-58.426182');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng2,
                map: map,
                title:"Pappo",
                icon: image
            });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="LoadGmaps()" onunload="GUnload()">
<!-- Maps DIV : you can move the code below to where you want the maps to be displayed -->
<div id="MyGmaps" style="width:100%;height:550px;border:1px solid #CECECE;"></div>
<!-- End of Maps DIV -->
</body>
</html>
```

The code is very long but it just query the database, extract the latitude and longitude, and converts it to a format I can actually use for google maps. Finally, the only variables I care are:

**$nombre_format_lat** and **$nombre_format_long**

But this way, the whole map is going to be reloaded every 10 seconds, which is very uncomfortable and I am planning to sell a service based on this website. I need to retrieve the latitude and longitude every 10 seconds but only reloading the marker! I tried to write the setInterval function inside the HTML code and calling the $nombre_format_lat and $nombre_format_long variables, but since I'm not fetching the database, those values will always be the same.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: Remove the @ in `@$_SESSION`

Comment: Can't you keep the map client-side and poll using AJAX? Remember the timestamp of the last LAT/LON pair collected then request all points stored since then with each poll.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, I thought the same, but honestly I am not very skilled programming and I don't know AJAX. Could you please help me with some small code sample applied to this situation?

Comment: Perhaps [Mike Williams' explanation of AJAX in his v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic11.htm) might help.  The concepts apply to your v3 map.

Comment: Thanks all, I found the answer in AJAX